# File error on opening spreadsheet created with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: excel, perl

I was using  [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) to create xls file using perl. When the range of spreadsheet increased, the Microsoft excel shows an alert before opening the file "**File Error: Data may have been lost**".

Please help me to solve this.

Here is the code

```
my $row = 2;
foreach my $sid(array of students objects)
{
        my $s = $students->{$sid};
    my $cc = 0;
my $wall = f1($x, $y, $z);#f1 is a method returns hash of arrays that have to write on excel having keys @key_array
foreach my $key (@key_array) {
my $t_row = $row;
my $i_c = 0;
my $t_col = 0;
my $m_row = $max_row;
while($m_row > 0){
    $t_col = 3+($cc*7);
    if($cc == 0){
    $ws->write($t_row, 0,
                [$s->{first_name}, $s->{last_name}, $s->{l_name}], $fmt_wrap    
            );
    }
    if(defined $wall->{$key}->[$i_c] ){
    $ws->write($t_row, $t_col, $wall->{$key}->[$i_c], $fmt_wrap);
    } else {
    $ws->write($t_row, (3+$cc*7),["","","","","","",""], $fmt_wrap);                
    }
    $t_row++;
    $i_c++;
    $m_row--;
 }#while loop
    $ws->write($t_row-1, 3+$company_format*$max_step,
                [ (scalar keys %{$s->{videos}}), $s->{total_pageviews} ], $fmt
            );
 $cc++;
 $t_row = 2;
}#foreach loop
$row+=$max_row;
}#foreach student array
```

Comment: Going to need more than that to be able to answer. Please see [ask] for some hints on how to assemble an answerable question.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your reply. I have added the part of code that i had editted. Before the generated Spreadsheet was working fine. It is working in Libre Office Calc which is a linux software fine. The problem is with Microsoft Excel. The modified code has only increased the number of columns to BP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer. In the code there was a line which write data into a cell multiple times. So i found that multiple write attempt to a particular cell can cause file corruption.