# Parse Excel data raises "File error"

Tags: excel, perl

I have three functions in a Perl script to parse an Excel file to getthe desired output Excel file.  I achieved the correct output, however I get an error

> File error: data may have been lost

Likely the root cause is writing over the same Excel cell twice in the file.

How do I get rid of this error while maintaining the functions in the script?

#### Input file

```
  A             B
Apples       Carrots
Oranges      Broccoli
Grapes       Spinach
```

#### Desire output file

```
  A             B
Apples       Carrots
Oranges      Broccoli
PEACHES      ASPARAGUS
```

#### Perl code

```perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $parser     = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook_R = $parser->parse('C:\Perl\databases\Fruits_and_Veggies.xls');

my $workbook_W  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('C:\Perl\databases\New_Fruits_and_Veggies.xls');
my $worksheet_W = $workbook_W->add_worksheet();

for our $worksheet_R ( $workbook_R->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_R->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_R->col_range(); 

    for our $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

        for our $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            FruitStand();

            VeggieStand();

            ComboStand();


            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # sub FruitStand - parsing: replace Grapes with PEACHES
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            sub FruitStand {

                # if the cell contains Grapes write 'PEACHES' instead
                my $cell_grapes = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );

                if ( $cell_grapes->value() =~ /Grapes/ ) {
                    $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,"PEACHES");
                }
            }


            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # sub VeggieStand - parsing: repalce Spinach with ASPARAGUS
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            sub VeggieStand {

                # if the cell contains Spinach write 'ASPARAGUS' instead
                my $cell_veggies = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
                # my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );

                if (/ $cell_veggies->value() =~ /Spinach/ ) {
                    $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,"ASPARAGUS");
                }
            }

            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Writing all fruits and veggies with the 2 changes (PEACHES and ASPARAGUS)
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            sub ComboStand {

                my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
                $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $cell->value()) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [File error on opening spreadsheet created with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001791/file-error-on-opening-spreadsheet-created-with-spreadsheetwriteexcel)

Comment: The error is coming from the same source (a cell being written several times) -- I understand that you want to eliminate the error and are asking how to do that. The "possible duplicate" will help others who come across the same error see other related posts.

Comment: OK.  Trying my best.

Comment: @user1608954: Please don't be so quick to dismiss offers of help that you have asked for. The linked question looks identical to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, the error message is due to a cell being written several times. You can get rid of the error message by ensuring that each cell is only written once. Since your three subroutines have very similar functionality, they can be combined into a single set of lines that does everything, and use an `if` / `else` cascade to decide which action should be taken.

```
for our $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
  for our $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

    my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
    if($cell->value() =~ /Spinach/) {
      $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,"ASPARAGUS");
    }
    elsif($cell->value() =~ /Grapes/) {
      $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,"PEACHES");
    }
    else {
      $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $cell->value()) ;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have to keep the functions, I suggest something like this, where you have a function that takes the current cell and applies any appropriate transformations to it, and returns the text ready for output. This keeps the repetition of reading the cell and writing the cell out of the subroutines:

```
for our $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
  for our $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
    my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
    $worksheet_w->write( $row, $col, produce_check($cell->value) );
  }
}
```

And the `produce_check` sub that performs the swaps would also be a good place to do any text normalisations or other checks you might want to do on the input, e.g. removing extra whitespace, setting all the output to title case, etc.

```
sub produce_check {
  my $prod = shift;
  # maybe we have to make sure there's no trailing whitespace on $prod
  $prod =~ s/\s*$//;
  my %swaps = (
    grapes => 'peaches',
    spinach => 'asparagus',
    tins => 'cans',
    zuchini => 'zucchini'
  );
  # is $prod one of pieces of produce we have to swap?
  # perhaps our input is in a mixture of cases, uppercase, lowercase, titlecase
  # to avoid having to add all those variations to the %swaps hash, we convert
  # to lowercase using `lc`
  if ( $swaps{ lc($prod) } ) {
    $prod = $swaps{ lc($prod) };
  }
  # this line uses `ucfirst($prod)` to convert all output to titlecase.
  # You could also convert everything to lowercase ( `lc($prod)` ), to
  # uppercase ( `uc($prod)` ), or just leave it as-is by using `return $prod;`
  return ucfirst( $prod );
}
```

Comment: Thanks "I alarmed alien." BUT I need to keep my functions so it is modular and I can build on to that.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it while keeping the functions?

Comment: Yes -- but having separate functions for text replacement is a bit OTT for this kind of script. One of the other principles of good coding is "Don't Repeat Yourself", and having three functions that do very similar things (read cell content, possibly swap a word, write the cell content) would be a violation of that principle.

Comment: I am just thinking about growth of the database.  What if I have a huge excel file?  Would functions be the better way to handle it over if/elsif/else?  I'm thinking modular.

Comment: If there were a range of substitutions that you had to do, I would probably create a single function that took the cell contents as input, ran through the range of possible substitutions, and returned whatever the new cell contents should be (either a different word or the same text). I'll add a small example to the answer.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks "I alarmed alien."

Comment: After a day later, still thinking about this brilliant solution, placing the function inside of $worksheet_w->write.  Thanks again.