# Using Perl Excel to Loop Through A Single Column and Not Every Columns

Tags: excel, perl, xls

My current Perl code loops through every row and every column in a Excel worksheet.

If I have 3 columns of data in Excel, how do I loop through only column 2 to read and write the specific data?  According to the data input below, the goal is to change the cell from Apples to Peaches.
Below is my code with the attempted solutions below the code.  I need Apples to be replaced with Peaches in Column 2, however Apples remain the same in column 1.

Note:  I answered my own question, yet it would be really be a good learning lesson if someone had a better solution.

INPUT:

```
  1           2           3
Grapes     Spinach     Mustard
Oranges    Apples      Ketchup
Apples     Potatoes    Horseradish
```

OUTPUT:

```
   1           2           3
Grapes     Spinach     Mustard
Oranges    Peaches     Ketchup
Apples     Potatoes    Horseradish
```

My code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook_R = $parser->parse('C:\Perl\databases\input.xls');

my $workbook_W = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('C:\Perl\databases\output.xls');
my $worksheet_W = $workbook_W->add_worksheet();

for my $worksheet_R ($workbook_R->worksheets()) {

my ($row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_R->row_range();
my ($col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_R->col_range(); 

  for my $row ($row_min .. $row_max ) {
  for my $col ($col_min .. $col_max ) {

  my $value = $worksheet_R->get_cell($row, $col)->value;

# Testing if Apples Replace Peaches
  $value =~ s/Apples/Peaches/g;
  $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $value);
  }
 }
}
```

Some of my solutions are:

```
   1)        my $value = $worksheet_R->get_cell($row, 2)->value;
   2)        $worksheet_W->write($row, 2, $value);
   3)        for my $col ($col == 2 ) {
```

All outcomes were incorrect data output.

Comment: You mentioned you've read other questions; have you attempted any solutions? I assume this is a homework assignment, correct? Obviously you didn't write this (or you'd know the answer)... it's fine to ask about homework or to 'borrow' code, but you do still need to show your attempt and explain the **specific* problem you're having other than "it's not working". See "[ask]" as well as info at the [help/on-topic] and also how to create a [mcve].  More good tips in this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Excel data raises "File error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767439/parse-excel-data-raises-file-error)

Comment: There are several posts on this site and others with answers to the **exact same question**.. Same sample data and everything. What a coincidence, eh? [**This will help you find them**.](https://www.google.ca/search?tbs=li%3A1&q=my+(%24row_min%2C+%24row_max+)+%3D+%24worksheet_R->row_range()++my+%24parser+%3D+Spreadsheet%3A%3AParseExcel%3A%3ASaveParser->new())

Comment: I am the author of those posts.

Comment: Read the questions.  They are asking totally different things.  There is more to a question than just the same variables.

Comment: You look at these questions, and see apples, and then you think these are the same questions.  NO.

Comment: You can ask 10000 different questions on the same data.  Read the questions, before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: My main point is that you haven't shown any attempt on this question.  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?  Are you getting an error? Where?  have you tried reducing the code to a [mcve]?

Comment: just run `perl -pe "s/(?<!^)Apples(?!$)/Peaches/" file.txt` this will change only column 2

Comment: @Onyambu -- Thanks for the alternative.  Trying discover more efficient ways than the normal textbook solutions.

Comment: fundamentals: if/else or something similar.

Comment: Not at all.  I preferred NOT to use the if/else solution.  That is why I asked for help.

Comment: Huh.. I might have misread your text.. I did not understand what you meant. Well let me know whether the code i provided helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the if/else statement for Column 2 and the other columns.

Here is the solution:

```
my $value = $worksheet_R->get_cell($row, $col)->value;

  if ($col ==1) {
# Apples Replace Peaches for ONLY Column 2
  $value =~ s/Apples/Peaches/g;
  $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $value);
  }
    else {
      # Print the other data in other columns
      $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $value);
  }
```

Comment: It works by writing the condition to only column 1 and writing all other data to the other columns.

Comment: Counting starts at 0. 0, 1 = 2 column.